# replace nth value of a csv line using sed in bash

Tags: csv, awk, sed

I have some csv like below

```
uid_01, joe, yes, no 
uid_02, sam, yes, maybe
uid_03, c, ruth, yes, maybe
uid_04, **alan**, no, yes
```

I want to replace **alan** with **ruby**, uid will be unique here. I need to change depending on $position, any idea how to get that in sed?

Also I want to give both pattern and replacement value as arguments.

Tried something like this, but working only at last entry

```
sed -i '/^'$uid',/s/[^,]*$/'$returnvalue'/' $OUTPUT
```

Thanks in advance, please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`awk` suits it better:

```sh
awk -v id='uid_04' -v repl='ruby' 'BEGIN {FS=OFS=", "}
$1 == id {$2 = repl} 1' file.csv

uid_01, joe, yes, no
uid_02, sam, yes, maybe
uid_03, c, ruth, yes, maybe
uid_04, ruby, no, yes
```

Comment: Thanks. Is there anyway to overwrite to the same file without taking a copy?

Comment: If you have `gnu-awk` then use `awk -i inplace -v id='uid_04' -v repl='ruby' 'BEGIN {FS=OFS=", "}
$1 == id {$2 = repl} 1' file.csv`

Comment: @SankaranKutty every Unix tool that has an option to enable "inplace" editing (`gawk -i inplace`, `perl -i`, `ruby -i`, `sed -i`, etc.) takes a copy of the file so - do you **really** care about taking a copy of the file or do you just not want to do it explicitly in your code with `cmd file > tmp && mv tmp file` and would prefer `cmd -i file` or `cmd -i inplace file`?

Comment: awk -v id1=$id -v repl='PASS' 'BEGIN {FS=OFS=","} ($1 == id1){$6 = repl} 1' $OUTPUT > tmp && mv tmp $OUTPUT

made it work, thanks guys. :)

@EdMorton - new to this, gawk is not present in the box, so i will go with this for time being. Thanks for the reply.

Comment: @anubhava Thank you

Could you tell me what that 1 near file name does?

Comment: That `1` is used to print each record. It is dummy condition that always returns `1`.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
id='uid_04' name='ruby' position=2
sed -i "/^$id,/s/[^,]*/ $name/$position" file
```

If the id is `uid_04` replace the second field by `ruby`

Comment: Sorry, its not working, 
sed: bad option in substitution expression